# A-frame specific animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, aframe, virtual-reality

I'm using a gltf model in my A-frame scene anf since the model has more than 1 animations available, I'm wondering how I can specify which animation to play. This is the code for my model:

```
       <a-gltf-model
scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"
      src="https://cdn.glitch.com/18a85eac-a71c-4578-ad89-80f59b3a68c3%2Fscene%20(95).glb?v=1619716622287" nimation-mixer="clip:Take 001; loop:2; timeScale: 1; crossFadeDuration: 1"
              animation__position1="
                property: position;
                from: 0 0 0;
                to: 0 0 -5;
                dur: 5000;
                easing: linear;
                autoplay: true;"
            animation__position2="
                property: position;
                from: 0 0 -5;
                to: 5 0 -5;
                dur: 5000;
                easing: linear;
                startEvents: animationcomplete__position1">
        </a-gltf-model>
```

and this is the model I download from sketchfab: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sci-fi-camera-drone-3dbf07385d1b471a96dce6de6cba97d6

The animation is currently not working and I'm wondering how I can get the model to animate like in sketchfab.

Answer (score 1):

You can [play `gltf-model` animations](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/gltf-model.html#using-animations) with the [`animation-mixer` component:](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders#animation)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-entity gltf-model="https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/assets/models/mech_drone/scene.gltf" 
              scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" position="0 0.5 -3" rotation="0 180 0" 
              animation-mixer></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Model by [Willy Decarpentrie](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/mech-drone-8d06874aac5246c59edb4adbe3606e0e)

---

Playing specific animations would require specifying a clip:

```
animation-mixer="clip: walk"
```